# Where to find RPM packages for CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, rpm

I need to download some RPM files for CentOS release 6.10. I noticed that CentOS-6 reached end of life. Is it still possible to find its RPM packages somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old versions of Centos can be found at http://vault.centos.org. You will probably find your packages at https://vault.centos.org/6.10/os/x86_64/Packages/; if not, a little searching will be required.